# Why is _designAttributes member private?

Tags: development, core

Here is another philosophical question.
In the category model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` all the members are `protected` except the  `$_designAttributes` member.
I know that they are special attributes but is there any reason for making this `private`?
To make the question a little broad, I see that there are some other members or methods in the core classes that are private and they don't make sense to me (a simple example `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::_decorateArrayObject` but there are more).

I will accept a 'These are some slip-ups of the developers' but only from a reliable source  - I'll decide who's reliable :)

Comment: Any findings other than it has been this way for a while? I found a source that showed it was this way in 1.2 and a guess before that also.

Comment: @DavidManners. It has been like that since the beginning. It's there in 1.1: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php#L53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento 2 the design attributes are not private anymore.
I can conclude that this was a slip-up or some inconsistency.
Not sure if I'm right, but since they were not kept private in M2 it means it was a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that if you were to extend the category model, chances are you'd not want to have these attributes defined as is. You may want similar functionality, though, so you'd assign your own attributes with different names. With the way Magento handles magic methods and attributes, I'm guessing they didn't want to expose invalid methods if those attributes were also invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really doubt that's the reason. I would say that if you extend the category model chances are you will leave these attributes as they are.